# How to add random code in a link?

Tags: javascript, php, random, text, hyperlink

I have a link on my website which I post in almost every post and which is like this `http://somedomain.com/thankyou/?data=abcde/AdJ8YEZAdd4ubfbW4Aztw2Ur/12345` .
where "abcde" and "12345" is a random test which I am currently adding myself. I need your help to make the "abcde" and "12345" random text to generate automatically in the link so that I don't have to add them by my self. the middle code "AdJ8YEZAdd4ubfbW4Aztw2Ur" is the main code

thank you very much, looking forward to receiving any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not that simillar

Comment: do you want this js or php?

Comment: i want to use java Script

Comment: @Oceanoffiles.com There would hardly be any exact 100% duplicate question but I can confidently say that your question is at least 80% similar. You just had to tweak the accepted answer a little bit.

Comment: i found a code i think which will work but i don't know how get the output of that code into the link

Comment: then dont tag the question with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are creating these urls through php in that case you can write something like

```
$url = 'http://somedomain.com/thankyou/?data=' . substr (str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),0,5) . '/AdJ8YEZAdd4ubfbW4Aztw2Ur/'  . rand(1500,9999)
```

in js you can do it like

```
var url = 'http://somedomain.com/thankyou/?data=' + (rand(--length, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)) + '') : '').substring(1, 5) + '/AdJ8YEZAdd4ubfbW4Aztw2Ur/' + Math.random()
```